# Calculating Discount Percentage of a given discounted price

Tags: php, math

I am trying to find out the discount amount of a price.

The cost of item WAS £50.00
Sale Price £25.00
Discount = %50

However when use this formula below in PHP it doesnt give me the correct Discount percentage.

```
$percent = $rowx->Orgprice - $rowx->SalePrice / 100;
$percent =  50 - 25 / 100 = 49.75; 
$percent =  50 - 20 / 100 = 49.8;
```

All above percentages are wrong.

Comment: You have used wrong formula to get percentage.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use this formula for calculating the discount percentage :

**Discount%=(Original Price - Sale price)/Original price*100**

Translating it into code, it should be something like :

```
$percent = (($rowx->Orgprice - $rowx->SalePrice)*100) /$rowx->Orgprice ;
```

Comment: No problem! Do add it as the accepted answer so that it may help  others as well  :)

Comment: This gives you the porcentage of how much the sale price correspond to the actual price, not the discount it self.

Comment: Here is a link with some examples on calculating discount percentage along with the formula as well. Kindly do check it out : http://www.math-only-math.com/discount-and-discount-percent.html  and also please upvote the answer again if you are convinced @PatrickBard

Comment: Sure, it was my mistake. I check many times before commenting here, trust me... What happened is that on Excel, instead of using "sale price", I've used the discount value by mistake. Since I couldn't figure it out that was referencing a the wrong value, I've concluded the formula was reversed. My bad, I'm so sorry... will change the vote as soon SO allow me.

Answer (score 6):

```
selling price = actual price - (actual price * (discount / 100))
```

So for example if (actual price) = $15, (discount) = 5%

```
selling price = 15 - (15 * (5 / 100)) = $14.25
```

Answer (score 5):

The correct formula is `1 - (sale price / original) * 100`, so:

```
$percent = 1 - ($rowx->SalePrice / $rowx->Orgprice) * 100;
$percent = 1 - (25 / 50) * 100 = 50
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope below code solved your problem :

```
 $percent =  100 * $rowx->SalePrice / $rowx->Orgprice;
 echo $percent;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

Original Selling Price = 15,
Discount = 5%

```
Original selling price *(1-discount) = sale price,

15*(1-.05)=14.25
```

If price values are known, but not percentage.

```
Sale price/Original selling price -1

14.25/15-1=-.05 so 5% discount
```